# Change function not firing in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some dropdown lists appended by jquery after a ajax request to the page. All of them has class `counter`. Now I want to set a change function for them but its not working at all. My jquery version is 1.9.1. I tried these:

```
$(".counter").on("change",function () {
    alert("ok");
});
```

And

```
$(".counter").change(function () {
    alert("ok");
});
```

Comment: Please show HTML too

Comment: Have you put this code in the doc ready block?

Comment: @Jai Yes.I have done it.

Comment: Check if jQuery library has been loaded and it should be loaded before your script.

Comment: @Justinas The html would be added dynamically.

Comment: @HamidReza now it seems to be clear enough, as you stated your html is dynamically added then you have to use event delegation syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content added dynamically so you have to use jQuery  `on` for dynamic content.

```
$(document).on("change",".counter",function () {
    alert("ok");
});
```

For jQuery 1.7+ you can attach an event handler to a parent element using .on(), and pass your class selector combined with 'document' as an argument.

See http://api.jquery.com/on/